# How to bind HBox or VBox content in Java FX

Tags: javafx, properties, binding, vbox, hbox

[image]

I have a HBox with a default shape in it and two buttons. Each can generate a triangle and place it in the SHAPE ObjectProperty. My problem is that I don't have a way to bind the HBox content to the ObjectProperty. Anybody has an idea about how to achieve this, please?

package stackOverflow;

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.application.Platform;
    import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
    import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
    import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
    import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
    import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class BoxContent extends Application
    {
        // property accessible to buttons
        ObjectProperty SHAPE = new SimpleObjectProperty();
        // shape method
        Polygon getDownGreenTriangle() {
            Polygon polygon = new Polygon(0.0, 0.0, 15.0, 0.0, 7.5, 15.0);
            polygon.setFill(Color.LIGHTGREEN);                
            return polygon; }
        // shape method
        Polygon getUpRedTriangle() {
            Polygon polygon = new Polygon(0.0, 0.0, 15.0, 0.0, 7.5, 15.0);
            polygon.setFill(Color.RED);
            SHAPE.set(polygon);
            return polygon; }
        // default circle
        Circle circle = new Circle(10, Color.GREY);

        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

                // box not available to buttons (how to bind content?)
                HBox hbox = new HBox();
                hbox.getChildren().add(circle);
                // buttons           
                Button GREEN = new Button("Green");
                Button RED = new Button("Red");

                // actions
                GREEN.setOnAction(e -> { 
                    Platform.runLater(() -> {                             
                        SHAPE.set(getDownGreenTriangle());
                    }); }); 
                RED.setOnAction(e -> { 
                    Platform.runLater(() -> { 
                        SHAPE.set(getDownGreenTriangle());
                    }); }); 


                // pane
                GridPane root = new GridPane();
                root.setHgap(10);
                root.setVgap(10);
                root.add(hbox, 1, 1);
                root.add(RED, 2, 1);
                root.add(GREEN, 3, 1);

                Scene scene = new Scene(root, 160, 45);
                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.show();
            } // end start

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Hi Sedrick I updated my question and code. The idea is that I don't want to add the triangles to the HBox using the getChildren().add() becuase the HBox is not available to the code which generates shapes based on some data. So I am looking for a way to bind HBox content at the time the HBox is instantiated and access its content later through its binding to an ObjectProperty. An alternative would be to bind its background fill property, but I will only keep the colour and loose the shape. Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: Reading `HBox is not available to the code which generates shapes based on some data.`. If I understand you correctly, to me this means you might have a design flaw or need to know how to pass data between `Controller`.

Comment: I achieved this setting a listener to the Property and generating the shape in the same class where the Hbox is defined, once the property value changes. I hope this helps someone.

Comment: You do not need to use `Platform.runLater` in event handlers for nodes. They are run on the JavaFX application thread.